# How to enable mail-r scope for Yahoo Developer Account

Tags: oauth, yahoo-api, yahoo-mail

I have registered my app at https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/BY4faaaa/

How can i grant scope for yahoo mail reading?
How can I enable `mail-r` scope since it is not being shown in the dashboard?

In this screenshot, are yahoo's [email scopes], but I can't see the one which grants permission to read emails of the authenticated user (https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/yahoo_scopes/)

[image: Yahoo email scopes]

Answer (score 1):

mail-r / mail-w are the correct scopes. I can confirm as I got it working.

I'll tell you Yahoo's dirty little secret: they hardcode a whitelist of acceptable applications. If your app is not in their list, you won't be able to access mail scopes.

Unless, of course, you use the "secret" key from [some other open-source app](https://searchfox.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/base/src/OAuth2Providers.jsm). Until they break it again, of course.

I think you'll be better off telling your clients to switch to a sane mail provider.

Comment: All sane providers have some sort of approval process. Google and Microsoft too.

Comment: Also, you can't really use secret from another app. There is a redirect URL at the end which won't redirect to your own app, unless it redirects back to localhost and specific port you are using as well. So if you want to use such a secret you'd have to match the port and the redirect URI.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot enable access to those scopes by yourself.

Scopes like:

`mail-r` (read only), `mail-w` (read+write) - IMAP (maybe also POP)

`sdct-r` (read only), `sdct-w` (read+write) - CardDAV

`ycal-r` (read only), `ycal-w` (read+write) - CalDAV

Those scopes are restricted so you have to request developer access from Yahoo. The only scopes which you have access to without the authorization from Yahoo are `openid`, `email` and `profile`.

**More information on requesting developer access to restricted scopes:**

- https://senders.yahooinc.com/developer/developer-access/

**Developer access request form:**

- https://senders.yahooinc.com/developer/developer-access-mail-form/

Answer (score 0):

You can either transmit in the request body using POST or as part of the query string with GET.

eg: `https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=lotsofletters&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://yahoo.com&scope=openid%20mail-r`

Also see: https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/getting_started.html#getting-started-setup

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot of the original post, Mail radio button is not showing for my newly create app. Therefore, I can't assign any permissions to read or write email.